# Incompatible Kotlin/Native libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

Android Studio 4.1.3

Brand new KMM project. All defaults accepted. No new code added, right out of the gate:

> Incompatible Kotlin/Native libraries
> There are 2 third-party libraries attached to the project that were compiled with an older Kotlin/Native compiler and cant be read in
> IDE:
> Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu-common:nativeInterop:0.15.1
> Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu-common:nativeMain:0.15.1
> Please edit Gradle buildfile(s) and specify library a version compatible with Kotlin/Native 1.4.32. Then re-import the project in
> IDE.

[image]

Why is this happening to a brand new project with all the defaults? Where do I find compatibility matrix? And where exactly do I need to change this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "libraries attached to project that were compiled with kotlin/native compiler" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766838/how-to-avoid-libraries-attached-to-project-that-were-compiled-with-kotlin-nativ)

Comment: thanks. will check out.